# JavaFx - How to use all vertical height (width) in the HBox with labels

Tags: javafx, label, fxml, scenebuilder, hbox

I need to design a java application using javaFx. In the fxml there is two hBoxes; one filled with text fields and one filled with labels. Every text fields and label hGrow set to ALWAYS but text fields do grow horizontaly but labels wont.

> *Note that I know I can set a Pref Width to 999999 on all of them and they will behave as I want, but there has to be a more legit way.*

Here is the fxml:

```
<VBox prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="640.0">
   <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <TextField promptText="ichi" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <TextField promptText="ni  " HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <TextField promptText="san " HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </HBox>
   <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
      <Label text="eins" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <Label text="zwei" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
      <Label text="drei" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
   </HBox>
</VBox>
```

As you can see all the hgrows set to ALYAWS but the results are like this:
[image: HBoxes; one filled with text fields, one filled with labels. Label one doesnt grow on horizontal]

Trying to fit all labels in to HBox with equal width distrubition. I figured a way but it is cheeky

Comment: Edit: Setting the prefWidth to 9999 or Infinity will result in affecting all the containers wrapping the hbox thus breaking all layouts  :D

Comment: You can [edit] your question to make any necessary changes.

Comment: This seems like a job for `GridPane` with the appropriate alignments/constraints set.

Comment: the javadoc is your friend :) see https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html - particularly the part about resizing constraint

Comment: You should set the `TextFields` and the `Labels` `Max Width` to `MAX_VALUE`. The `Pref Width` should be `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`.

Comment: I can't remember which one it should be, but either `Content Display` should be `Center` or `Alignment` should be `Center`. Play with the values to see which one. That's assuming you want the `Label` text centered.

Comment: Also, I 100% agree with @Slaw.

Comment: @Slaw The code above is just for demonstration, actual use is not grid like, just a single HBox. But if you mean by replace single HBoxes with GridPanes, thanks.

Comment: @SedJ601 Setting MAX Width to MAX_VALUE and Pref Width to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE did not make an affect on layout. Thanks.

Comment: I used the method i mentioned with quote. But instead of setting Prefered Width to 9999 i used a smaller number so the outer containers doesnt get effected. Still not a good solution but i couldnt find any other way :ı

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Key Code:**

```
Max Width = MAX_VALUE
Hgrow = ALWAYS
```

**Full code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <TextField maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="ichi" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <TextField maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="ni" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <TextField maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" promptText="san" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="eins" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="zwei" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="drei" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: When you add a `new VBox` with the same level with `our VBox`, new one gets crushed by old one because of `MAX_VALUE` [seen here](https://imgur.com/a/wnKlGKs)

Comment: But this answer checks out since I didn't mention this problem in the question.

Comment: How much space should the last `VBox` cover? It should be the same ideas if the `VBoxes` are going to each take half of the view.